# My intent is not matching with expected response

Tags: azure-language-understanding, botkit

I'm using `botkit` with `luis` recognizer and below is the sample code:

```
bot.dialog('OnboardingDialog', (session) => {
   ....
....

}).triggerAction({ matches: 'OnboardingBook' })
```

I have defined onboarding intent in responses as below:

OnboardingBook:{buttonTitle:'',url:'',response:'new hire can be onboarded some extra stuff',title:'Onboarding book'}

CookBook: `{buttonTitle:'',url:'',response:'this is about cookbook',title:'cook'}`

Ideally, if I type onboarding in my chat bot, it should return response defined in Onboarding intent. But right now its giving me other intent answer. If i type, onboarding book its giving me cook book intent.

Please help me out why few intents are matching with other than expected. Is there any logic behind this? How to resolve this problem. Please help me out.

Comment: When you [test your LUIS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-interactive-test) in the LUIS portal do you get the correct intent? If so then perhaps you need to [save and train](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-train), the [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-publish-app) your LUIS app again. If you do not get the correct result in the LUIS portal then you can click inspect and edit the top scoring intent (save + train then publish to push the change live).

Comment: Thanks my issue fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I have added my comment as an answer, please mark this as accepted so that other users will see your question as resolved when browsing the list. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [test your LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-interactive-test) app in the LUIS portal do you get the correct intent? If so then perhaps you need to [save and train](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-train), the [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-publish-app) your LUIS app again. If you do not get the correct result in the LUIS portal then you can click inspect and edit the top scoring intent (save + train then publish to push the change live).